# ¿Por qué cuando recargo la pagina mi API no funciona? REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

estoy probando con hacer una pagina de Super Héroes.
El problema esta en que cuando hago click en un héroe y me lleva a la sección de detalles la API deja de funcionar para algunos componentes, excepto para el atributo "Name" si quito los que fallan funciona, y lo mas loco es que cuando vuelvo a colocar los elementos que antes fallaban esta vez si funcionan hasta que recargo la pagina nuevamente y sale el error **"Cannot read property 'fullName' of undefined"**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Details = () => {
  const { heroId } = useParams();
  const [hero, setHero] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://akabab.github.io/superhero-api/api/id/" + heroId + ".json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setHero(response);
      });
  }, [heroId]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{hero.name}</h1>
      <h2>{hero.biography.fullName}</h2>
      <h3>{hero.biography.publisher}</h3>
      <img src={hero.images.md} alt={hero.name} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Details;
```

Alguien sabe en que estoy fallando?

Por lo que noté solo lee las propiedades que están en la "raiz" del Json como "name" y "slug"
IMAGEN
[image: Código del consoleLog]

Comment: El error `Cannot read property 'fullName' of undefined` indica que la propiedad `biography` no está definida en el objeto `hero`. Revisa la variable `response` antes de hacer el `setHero(response)`, debes verificar que realmente recibes el objeto con todos los atributos que esperas. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Si, me da el objeto completo con las propiedades que le pido, por eso me parece raro.
https://imgur.com/a/lGMJOLi

Comment: Entonces revisa el método `setHero()`, tal vez el problema se encuentra allí.